# Button setOnClickListener causing application crash

Tags: java, android, xml, button

So I have 2 XML layout files.
One is the menu and the other is the app.
So, now I have some buttons on the one XML file and some other buttons on the other file.

So this code works:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    start.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But if I change the view and write this:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.random);
    add_person = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

    add_person.setOnClickListener(this); //crash here
```

The app crashes!

Comment: Of course.The xml is created by eclipse with the gui builder.

http://codeviewer.org/view/code:25c0

Comment: change the id of the button to add in xml and onclick method

Comment: sry...the id in the xml is add. did you mean this line s?tart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
this line works.

Comment: @DennisNolte actually dennis the button with id add has to be in xml file random

Comment: here is the crash log:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:25c2

Comment: Dennis try after cleaning current project from project->clean

Comment: use (Button)random.findViewById(R.id.add); instead of  (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);

Comment: thanks imran...now it works....ok toaday i learned first clean then ask :D

Comment: @imrankhan i think is new here so we have to tell him how to accept an answer

Comment: Dennis i have posted my answer if it's working then u can accept it for others help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_person` is null so get Nullpointer Exception and you have Button in random.xml which has add as id?

if not then add

```
<Button android:id="@+id/add" ... />
```

Comment: yes i uploaded the xml in the comments. so another button doesnt work too. and it have also the right id in the xml and in the java class

Answer (score 0):

try after cleaning current project from *Project->Clean*.

or you can use

```
(Button)random.findViewById(R.id.add);
```

instead of

```
(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the class as `onClickListner` like this:

```
public class <ClassName> extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.button1:
                   //Hear Yor Logic on Click Event.
                   break;       
           }        
    }
}
```